Uso de Windows forms en python con Visual Studio
import clr

clr.addreference ("system.windows.forrms")

from clr.system.windows.forms import Aplication,form, button

El intérprete indica:
unresolved import 'clr.system'


Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Nunca he usado pythonnet, pero mirando por encima la documentación, ¿No debería ser clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms") y
from System.Windows.Forms import Application, Form, Button?

Por cierto, se me olvido mencionar que en principio ese "error" no es del intéprete, el cual generaría un AttributError/ModuleNotFoundError/ImportError dependiendo del caso. Eso tiene pinta se ser un aviso (warning) del analizador de código del IDE (¿pylint?) y pueden ser falsos positivos. Ejecuta siempre el código para asegurarte de que es un error real y de que el intéprete  efectivamente lanza una excepción y no es un problema/limitación con el analizador estático del IDE y no con el código.

He encontrado que es una incompatibilidad entre versiones de Python y PythonNet, probé lo más posible  -las viejas versiones ya no tiene instalador - y nada, buscaré otro tipo de form y no de .Net. cerraré el tema, gracias.

Tal vez debas usar IronPython.
